# UCI rules on allowed brakes?

Tags: brakes, uci

I'm considering buying a TriRig Omega X braking system front & rear for a bike I intend to use in UCI events. I can't find the right document on their respective website, so I'm asking here hoping someone could elucidate whether or not the TriRig brakes are legal?

[image: From https://www.tririg.com/store.php?c=omega] 
from https://www.tririg.com/store.php?c=omega

Comment: what is the "right document"? what is it about these brakes that makes you think they wouldn't be allowed?

Comment: What about information and support from the manufacturer?

Comment: Which UCI cycle sport are you entering? Usually your national governing body (ie British Cycling here in the UK) have the same rules.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

this is Nick the owner of TriRig and the designer of the brake.

Short answer: yes, Omega X has been allowed to race in all stripes of UCI events, up to and including multiple appearances in the Tour de France.

So generally, it appears it has been ruled legal. Of course, there is some level of unpredictability in how any given commissaire will rule on any given day at any given event. We have heard a couple rogue reports of the commissaire requiring the Front Plate to be removed. But in general, you should not have a problem. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome - thank you for joining SE to answer this question.

Answer (score 7):

I assume your concern is the cover which exists solely to make the brake body more aerodynamic and thus would appear to potentially fall foul of the "no non-structural fairings" rule.  Fortunately for you, brakes get an explicit exemption in the rules.  Per [UCI's clarification guide](https://www.uci.org/docs/default-source/equipment/clarificationguideoftheucitechnicalregulation-2018-05-02-eng_english.pdf?sfvrsn=fd56e265_58):

> The addition of a cover to a braking system ... is authorised. The
>   unit is considered to be integrated with the frame or fork.
>
> The combination of the frame tube (or fork tube) + brake + cover must respect the minimum
>   and maximum dimension rules and must be contained completely within the corresponding
>   8 cm box.

It then goes on to explain the 8 cm box, which basically means that the combined depth of the brake and the fork crown cannot be more than 8cm.  Now I'm not sure what the TriRig's exact depth is, nor do I know what fork you'd be pairing it with, but 8 cm is quite deep and I'd be very surprised if you managed to exceed it.

For one final piece of evidence, note that TriRig claims their brakes have been run at le Tour de France.  Sure enough, it appears that, at the very least, they were run by Cofidis in the 2013 Tour TT stages.  If there is any race in the world where the bikes are scrutinized by the UCI, le Tour would be it, so if they've been run there, they should be fine for any race you might enter.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're in the US, UCI rules on bicycles in general do not apply.

Actual UCI rules only apply "at events that select 17-18, U23 and Elite riders for international competition or national teams. All bicycles used in National Championships (for UCI recognized classes listed above) and NRC races must comply with the current UCI regulations."

See [**1. General Regulations**, 1I1, paragraph f (p. 27)](https://s3.amazonaws.com/craft-prod-assets/documents/Rules-Policies/USAC_RuleBook_2019_Chpt_01.pdf):

> (f) Bicycles must meet current UCI technical regulations at events
>   that select 17-18, U23 and Elite riders for international competition
>   or national teams. All bicycles used in National Championships (for
>   UCI recognized classes listed above) and NRC races must comply with
>   the current UCI regulations. At the discretion of USA Cycling, UCI
>   rules may be adopted or modified for other National Championships.

I seem to remember a huge driver for this "loose interpretation" for a "legal bicycle" is to allow the use of triathlon-specific bicycles that don't meet UCI regulations in lower-level races.  No one wanted to prevent triathletes from participating in USA Cycling time trials with triathlon bikes that don't meet UCI regulations (3-1 aspect ratios, etc) or force them to buy another UCI-legal time trial bike.

Note, however, paragraph b (bolding per original):

> (b) There may be no **protective shield,** fairing, or other device on any part of the bicycle, which has the effect of reducing air resistance except that spoke covers may be used.

In my experience with USA Cycling events, I've never seen a bicycle equipment check.  If what you're riding looks like a legal bike you should be fine, although it's impossible to rule out someone enforcing a strict interpretation of that rule.

I'd say USA Cycling's attitude seems to me to be, "If you're not good enough that someone else gives you a bike to race on, we don't really care if what you race on is exactly UCI legal or not."